# Yii2: Как сделать определнные ячейки редактируемыми?

Tags: yii2, gridview, kartik

Можно ли в kartik gridview как-то обратиться к определенным ячейкам? Нужно добавить проверку, если значение ячейки удовлетворяет условию, то ее можно редактировать, если нет, то нет соотвественно. Можно например к колонке добавить 'readonly', но как сделать что-то подобное отдельно для определенной ячейки, не могу понять.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'name',
    ],
],
```

Comment: То есть Вам нужно в стандартный GridView в ячейку с контентом вставить свой текстовый input, при вводе данных в который происходит сохранение в базу данных?

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $requests,
  'options' => ['class' => 'yourCssClassName'],
  'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
  'columns' => 
  [
   [
     'attribute' => 'name',
     'format' => 'raw',
     'value' => function ($model) {
       $value = '';
       //также можно тернарным оператором
       //тогда код сократим
       if($model->name === 'editable') {
       $value = Html::a($model->name, ['/news/update', 'id' => $model->id)
       } else {
       $value = $model->name
       }
       return $value;
     },
    ],
 ]);?>
```